# Kafka-python lib Invalid file object: None

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

i try to create consumer in python but i got a problem.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'mykafkatopic',
    bootstrap_servers='mykafkaserver:9092',
    group_id='airflow_consumer_test',
    auto_offset_reset='earliest'
)

for msg in consumer:
    print(msg.value)
```

when i try to run it, i got this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ivlasov/pyCharm/pythonProject/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\group.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 909, in check_version
    version = conn.check_version(timeout=remaining, strict=strict, topics=list(self.config['bootstrap_topics_filter']))
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 1254, in check_version
    selector.register(self._sock, selectors.EVENT_READ)
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selectors.py", line 299, in register
    key = super().register(fileobj, events, data)
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selectors.py", line 238, in register
    key = SelectorKey(fileobj, self._fileobj_lookup(fileobj), events, data)
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selectors.py", line 225, in _fileobj_lookup
    return _fileobj_to_fd(fileobj)
  File "C:\Users\ivlasov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selectors.py", line 39, in _fileobj_to_fd
    raise ValueError("Invalid file object: "
ValueError: Invalid file object: None

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If someone knows the solution to this problem, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Not sure. Maybe try a different library? `confluent-kafka-python`

Comment: I tried what you suggested, got new exception (might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 ) . so , maybe problem on kafka side, thank you for your answer

Comment: Well, are either of those things true?

Comment: yeah, the problem was in broker version

Comment: Okay. Feel free to provide a full answer below in more detail

Comment: @YuriiVlasov can you please provide the snippet code of your fix please?

Comment: @BasselKh sorry, i lost it. as long as I remember we fixed it with update broker version